# Python or Java for text processing (text mining, information retrieval, natural language processing)

Tags: java, python, nlp, information-retrieval, text-mining

I'm soon to start on a new project where I am going to do lots of text processing tasks like searching, categorization/classifying, clustering, and so on.

There's going to be a huge amount of documents that need to be processed; probably millions of documents. After the initial processing, it also has to be able to be updated daily with multiple new documents.

Can I use Python to do this, or is Python too slow? Is it best to use Java?

If possible, I would prefer Python since that's what I have been using lately. Plus, I would finish the coding part much faster. But it all depends on Python's speed. I have used Python for some small scale text processing tasks with only a couple of thousand documents, but I am not sure how well it scales up.

Answer (score 18):

Both are good. Java has a lot of steam going into text processing. [Stanford](http://nlp.stanford.edu/)'s text processing system, [OpenNLP](http://incubator.apache.org/opennlp/), [UIMA](http://uima-framework.sourceforge.net/), and [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/) seem to be the big players (I know I am missing some). You can literally run the StanfordNLP module on a large corpus after a few minutes of playing with it. But, it has major memory requirements (3 GB or so when I was using it).

[NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/), [Gensim](http://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projekty/gensim/), [Pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern), and many other Python modules are very good at text processing. Their memory usage and performance are very reasonable.

Python scales up because text processing is a very easily scalable problem. You can use multiprocessing very easily when parsing/tagging/chunking/extracting documents. Once your get your text into any sort of feature vector, then you can use numpy arrays, and we all know how great numpy is...

I learned with NLTK, and Python has helped me greatly in reducing development time, so I opine that you give that a shot first. They have a very helpful mailing list as well, which I suggest you join.

If you have custom scripts, you might want to check out how well they perform with [PyPy](http://pypy.org/).

Comment: I think this is a good overview of packages used for the NLP side of a project. Another thing to consider is the machine learning side. Though I am only familiar with the Java libraries - WEKA, MALLET, Apache Mahout.

Answer (score 9):

It's very difficult to answer questions like this without trying. So why don't you

1. Figure out what would be a difficult operation
2. Implement that (and I mean the simplest, quickest hack that you can make work)
3. Run it with a **lot** of data, and see how long it takes
4. Figure out if it's too slow

I've done this in the past and it's really *the* way to see if something performs well enough for something.

Answer (score 3):

Just write it, the biggest flaw in programming people have is premature optimization. Work on a project, write it out and get it working. Then go back and fix the bugs and ensure that its optimized. There are going to be a number of people harping on about speed of x vs y and y is better than x but at the end of a day its just a language. Its not what a language is but how it does it.

Answer (score 2):

it's not language you have to evaluate, but frameworks and app servers for clustering, data storage/retrieval etc available for the language.

you can use jython and use all the java enterprise technologies for high load system and do text parsing with python.

Comment: I have never used Jython. I read that it is slower than Python. But I guess it might be made faster than Python by converting critical parts of code into java? is that correct?

Comment: @user757256: yes, jython is slightly slower and is much more memory-hungry. Hack some prototype, benchmark with CPython and Jython, then see what you can optimize. And again, make your choice only after evaluating which libraries you can use.