# Sort words by their usage

Tags: python, nltk

I have a list of english words (approx 10000) and I'd like to sort them by their usage as they occur in literature, newspaper, blogs etc. Can I sort them in Python or other language? I heard about `NLTK` which is the closest library I know that could help. Or is this task for other tool?

thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python and NLTK are the perfect tools to sort your wordlist, as the NLTK comes with some corpora of the english language, from which you can extract frequency information.

The following code will print a given `wordlist` in the order of word frequency in the brown corpus:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown

wordlist = ["corpus","house","the","Peter","asdf"]
# collect frequency information from brown corpus, might take a few seconds
freqs = nltk.FreqDist([w.lower() for w in brown.words()])
# sort wordlist by word frequency
wordlist_sorted = sorted(wordlist, key=lambda x: freqs[x.lower()], reverse=True)
# print the sorted list
for w in wordlist_sorted:
    print w
```

output:

```
>>> 
the
house
Peter
corpus
asdf
```

If you want to use a different corpus or get more information you should have a look at [chapter 2 of the nltk book](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch02.html#brown-corpus).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). The code is then as easy as :

```
l = get_iterable_or_list_of_words() # That is up to you
c = collections.Counter(l)
print(c.most_common())
```

Comment: I'm looking for some library that will look up the words in some database that is available to download or online and has the statistics of usages (because I don't have the statistics).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about natural language processing, but I think Python is an ideal language for you to use for the purpose.

A Google search for "Python natural language" found:

http://www.nltk.org/

A search of StackOverflow found this answer:

[Python or Java for text processing (text mining, information retrieval, natural language processing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030291/python-or-java-for-text-processing-text-mining-information-retrieval-natural-l/6031333#6031333)

Which in turn linked to Pattern:

http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern

You might want to take a look at Pattern, that seems promising.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: The tools are useful but do they do what I asked for?